# android SIP API getPeerProfile null

Tags: android, sip, voip

I'm using the Android SIP API and have the folowing situation.
When I receive an incoming call and the call is ended without answering the call `( = missed call)`, the peer SIPProfile is null inside `onCallEnded()` of my `SipAudioCall.Listener`.

```
SipProfile peerProfile = call.getPeerProfile();
```

This returns null. But the same code inside `onCallEstablished()` returns not null.
I need the SIPProfile for showing the name of the caller.
Is this a bug or how can I fix this?

**Edit/Solution**:
Could not find the answer but here is the "trick" to get the peer profile.

1. create your SipAudioCall object

   `incomingCall = mSipManager.takeAudioCall(incomingCallIntent, listener);`
2. get peer profile 
   `SipProfile peerProfile = incomingCall.getPeerProfile();`

Now you can get the UriString and display it in your UI.